# How to determine whether an App is universal from info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

Is there a special key-value pair in info.plist that can tell whether an App is universal?

If not, can we determine this indirectly through other key-value pairs?

Comment: Don't you just "know" if the app is universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the app is built, you can look at the `UIDeviceFamily` key in the bundle's Info.plist to see what families it lists. As far as I can tell, `1` is the iPhone family and `2` is the iPad family; the key will have an array of supported families, and will contain both numbers if the app is universal.

Before the app is built, the only universal toggle is in the Xcode project (your .pbxproj file), not in the Info.plist itself.